# DSL connection problem after installing Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: networking, internet, network-manager, 15.04

I have just installed Ubuntu 15.04. I tried to connect with my broadband DSL connection. When I entered the cable it was showing that it could recognize the cable. Then from edit connection I added a new DSL Network Connection and configured with my username and password. Then when I tried to connect through the new configured DSL connection it prompts up a message saying "**Connection activation failed. (1) Creating object for path '/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/5' failed in libnm-glib.**". 
Here is the screenshot of the prompt: http://pasteboard.co/3HlwTSl.png

What is the problem? How do I resolve it?

Comment: Are you sure you added the right 'security' key?

Comment: It didn't asked me any security key while installing it.

Comment: @K.K Patel <br>
i cant connect to internet at all <br>
can you give me link to .deb package of network-manager

Answer (score 1):

It seems that network-manager is broken.

Download network-manager packages by following command while internet connection is active.

```
sudo apt-get install -d --reinstall network-manager network-manager-gnome
```

Purge network-manager packages.

```
sudo apt-get purge network-manager-gnome network-manager
```

Reboot the system and re-install it.

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager-gnome network-manager
```

Comment: Didn't help me. Still getting the same message.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem in Ubuntu Mate 15.04. "sudo pppoeconf" in terminal got a working DSL connection. It asks several configuration questions, then it is possible to connect with "pon dsl-provider" and disconnect with "poff dsl-provider". Added two buttons with these commands on panel and removed network-manager from startup apps for now.