# 16.04 can't connect via DSL

Tags: internet, network-manager, 16.04, dsl

I am on a DSL network which wont connect in Ubuntu 16.04. Tried all the mentioned solutions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/615234/dsl-connection-problem-after-installing-ubuntu-15-04), none of them worked. Also `pon dsl-provider` is not an option for me.

Comment: I faced the same issue, it looks like bug with network manager.

Comment: This issue was fixed in Ubuntu 16.04.1

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work by adding a new dsl connection through sudo pppoeconf, and also making the same dsl connection in Network Connections, then running pon dsl-provider, then reboot.

Comment: How to create the same  dsl connection using Network Connections? Should i use 'dsl-provider' as name of the connection?

Comment: Network Connections from Dash, Add, select DSL , Create. You can use whatever name, it's not important.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the solution, I'll try and let you know.

Comment: So, I tried as you mentioned, unfortunately it didn't work, First I created a DSL connection from 'sudo pppoeconf' , after that created the same connection from network manager. After reboot, network indicator shows connected to the internet which is wrong, also, network indicator menu does not have any of the created connections, neither a way to disconnect, indicator icon doesn't get updated when i run 'pon /poff dsl-provider', just totally unresponsive.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue (DSL working in 14.04 and not working in 16.04). The solution was to set ppp MTU to 1492. This can be done by editing the "DSL Connection 1" file in /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections and adding mtu=1492 after the [ppp] line like this:

```
[ppp]
lcp-echo-failure=5
lcp-echo-interval=30
mtu=1492
```

Another way to set it is through the command: *ifconfig ppp0 mtu 1492*